# Getting current day date instead of api requested date Moment.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

i have a question im receiving a data from api request and mapping in my front end so i want to use moment.js to format my data but when i format it gets the todays date instead the date received from the api here i wanted to convert my date to string and pass the day in number instead of all the date

```
{consulta.map(data => (
            <Consulta key={data.animalID.animalName} imagem={data.animalID.imagem} animal={data.animalID.animalName} dia={data.hora} mes={data.hora} hora={data.hora} vet={data.vet.name} appointmentType={data.appointmentType} razao={data.razao} />
        ))}
```

and

```
const Consulta = ({ animal, dia, mes, hora, imagem, vet, appointmentType, razao }) => {
const styles = {
    labelNome: {
        color: "#FFFFFF",
        marginTop: -20,
    },
    labelDia: {
        color: "#FFFFFF",
        fontSize: '25px',
        marginTop: -15,
    },
    labelMes: {
        color: "#FFFFFF",
        fontSize: '17px',
        fontWeight: 'lighter',
        marginTop: -20,
    },
    div: {
        marginTop: '-5%',
    }

};
// dia = moment(dia).format('DD');
// mes = moment(mes).format('MMM');
// hora = moment(hora).format('h:mm');
return (
    <div style={styles.div}>
        <div className='rectangle'>
            <img className="imagemAnimal" src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${imagem}`}></img>
            <div className='consultasAnimalInfo'>
                <label style={styles.labelNome}>{animal}</label>
                <label style={styles.labelDia}>{moment(dia.createdAt).format('DD')}
                </label>
                <label style={styles.labelMes}>{mes}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="infoConsulta">
            <div className="infoC">
                <p>Horas</p>
                <p>Veterinário</p>
                <p>Tipo de Consulta</p>
                <p>Razão</p>
            </div>
            <div className='consultasContent'>
                <p>{hora}</p>
                <p>{vet}</p>
                <p>{appointmentType}</p>
                <p>{razao}</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)}
```

Comment: You can't pass just the hours to moment() and expect it to detect this. How is moment supposed to distinguish `moment(11)` (hours) from `moment(11)` (date)? Please provide the exact API output.

Comment: api output https://prnt.sc/11qzfzp i want to gwt the day and pass the number but it gets the current day

Comment: moment doesn't know how to parse `"19-04-2021 13:13"` since that's a custom format.

Comment: so i cant do anything?

Comment: You can parse the string using a regular expression: https://jsfiddle.net/wts6oukb/